# Calling class function within a constructor isn't being recognised

Tags: coffeescript

## Answer:

It turns out I had neglected to use the `new` keyword when creating the class instance. The code in the question itself is fine.

## Question:

I have a fairly simple class where the constructor calls another method on the class (editor_for_node). The call happens inside a jQuery each() loop, but I've also tried moving it outside.

```
define ['jquery'], ($) ->
  class Editor
    constructor: (@node, @data, @template) ->
      @node.widgets().each (i, elem) =>
        data = if @data then @data[i] else null
        node = $(elem)
        @editor_for_node node, data

    editor_for_node: (node, data) ->
      console.log 'hello!'

  return {
    'Editor': Editor,
  }
```

When the line `@editor_for_node node, data` gets called, I get an error (in Firebug) saying `this.editor_for_node is not a function`.

I really can't see why this isn't working properly, the only possible source of weirdness that I can see is my use of require.js's define function at the start.

## Edit: Generated output

```
(function() {

  define(['jquery'], function($) {
    var Editor;
    Editor = (function() {

      Editor.name = 'Editor';

      function Editor(node, data, template) {
        var _this = this;
        this.node = node;
        this.data = data;
        this.template = template;
        this.node.widgets().each(function(i, elem) {
          data = _this.data ? _this.data[i] : null;
          node = $(elem);
          return _this.editor_for_node(node, data);
        });
      }

      Editor.prototype.editor_for_node = function(node, data) {
        return console.log('hello!');
      };

      return Editor;

    })();
    return {
      'Editor': Editor
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: Which version of CoffeeScript are you using? The fat arrow has been a source of bugs in certain previous releases.

If you're using the latest (1.3.1), then I'm going to go ahead and say that this is an indentation issue. When I copy and paste your code, it works fine. Are you mixing tabs and spaces? Verify that the compiled output contains the line

```
Editor.prototype.editor_for_node = ...
```

**Update:** See the comments on this answer. Turns out the problem was that the `new` keyword wasn't being used when invoking the constructor.

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks for your quick answer. I'm using CoffeeScript 1.3.1. I'd be surprised if it was an indentation issue, I come from a Python background, so I'm used to the quirks of indentation-based syntax. I'll add the generated code to the question.

Comment: The generated code looks fine. Now I'm thinking that the problem is how you're calling the constructor, e.g. are you forgetting to use the `new` keyword?

Comment: Aha! I'm so used to not using `new` that I didn't spot that CoffeeScript requires it. That seems to have sorted it. I'll update the question to reflect this, feel free to update your answer too. Thanks!